# Observable returned from function never sends onNext

Tags: swift, rx-swift, reactive

I have and observable that never sends onNext if its returned by a function, but if i subscribe to it in the function that returns it, onNext is called.

```
class InfoViewModel {

    func refreshPushToken() {

        PushNotificationService.sharedInstance.pushToken!
                .flatMapLatest { (pushToken: String) -> Observable<Result<User>> in
                    return UserService.registerPushToken(pushToken)
                }
                .subscribe { (event ) in
                    print(event)
                }
                .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

    }
}

struct UserService {
    ....
    static func registerPushToken(_ pushToken: String) -> Observable<Result<User>> {
        ...
        return self.postUser(user: user)
    }

    static fileprivate func postUser(user: User) -> Observable<Result<User>> {

        let rxProvider: RxMoyaProvider<Backend> = RxMoyaProvider<Backend>(endpointClosure: Backend.endpointClosure)

         return rxProvider.request(Backend.register(user: user))
            .mapObject(type: User.self)
            .map({ (user: User) -> Result<User> in
                LogService.log(level: .debug, action: "postUser", message: "Posted user with success", parameters: ["user": user.deviceId])
                return .success(user)
            })
            .catchError({ error -> Observable<Result<User>> in
                LogService.log(level: .error, action: "postUser", message: "Error posting user", parameters: ["user": user.deviceId, "error": error.localizedDescription])
                return Observable.just(.failure(error))
            })
    }   
}
```

But if I do this

```
     rxProvider.request(Backend.register(user: user))
     ...
        .subscribe { (event ) in
            print(event)
        }
```

in the UserService, i will get a next event.

I have tried to use `debug()` on the observable in InfoViewModel, there is a subscription, i just never receive any events.

Comment: Added line numbers, i figured that images could show the two files better.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question 
I'm just trying to help you get your question answered quicker ^^

Comment: Will c/p code ASAP

Comment: Observables do not provide values unless you subscribe to them. That's how they work.

Comment: Which I do in the InfoViewModel, i know about hot and cold observables.

Comment: Would you kindly remove the downvote since i have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured it out, I was creating the RxMoyaProvider inside the method, so as soon as i went out of the scope of the method, it was deallocated. Which means that when was subscribing to it, it could no longer create the request. The reason that this wouldn't fail is because of how the observable is created

```
open func request(_ token: Target) -> Observable<Response> {

        // Creates an observable that starts a request each time it's subscribed to.
        return Observable.create { [weak self] observer in
            let cancellableToken = self?.request(token) { result in
                switch result {
                case let .success(response):
                    observer.onNext(response)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                case let .failure(error):
                    observer.onError(error)
                }
            }

            return Disposables.create {
                cancellableToken?.cancel()
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the request is called upon subscription, but since `self` had been deallocated the request was never fired. And all i got back was an empty observable.